# Connecting Wall: Pairing Up

Tags: wordplay, connect-wall

This is a connecting wall with a twist. Instead of 16 single words, this connecting wall has pairs of words. As usual, find the four groups which connect the pairs, bearing in mind it might not be simple.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sweets, Stressed | State, Art | Blue, Money | Laughing, Market |
| Fire, Pay | Rest, Peels | Treasure, Mint | Salt, Earth |
| Rodents, Star | Peach, Gala | Borrowed, Travel | Cream, Crop |
| Empire, Needy | Change, Guard | Trolleys, Smart | Sunshine, Frail |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The four groups are:

> **Reversing Y gives a synonym of X:**
>  Sweets, Stressed
>  Trolleys, Smart
>  Rodents, Star
>  Rest, Peels
>
>  **"X of the Y" phrases:**
>  Salt, Earth
>  Cream, Crop
>  Change, Guard
>  State, Art
>
>  **"X _" and "_ Y" are both common phrases:**
>  Laughing, Market [STOCK]
>  Blue, Money [BLOOD]
>  Borrowed, Travel [TIME]
>  Fire, Pay [BACK (or HAZARD, as pointed out by Stiv)]
>
>  **X is a state nickname; that state's abbreviation is the first and last letters of Y:**
>  Sunshine, Frail [FLORIDA]
>  Empire, Needy [NEW YORK]
>  Peach, Gala  [GEORGIA]
>  Treasure, Mint [MONTANA]

Comment: You got one of the third connections wrong.

Comment: I think FIRE/PAY should probably be related to [this](https://www.dol.gov/general/topic/wages/hazardpay).